# Ideal of regular functions in $Z(xy-z^2)$ vanishing on $(x,y)$ is not principal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $H = Z(xy-z^2) \subset \Bbb A ^ {3}$.

And let $L = Z(x,z)$.

I need to show that  $L \subset H$ , that $dim(L) = dim (H) -1$ and that the ideal of regular functions on $H$ which vanishing on $L$ is not a principal ideal.

So showing $L\subset H$ is easy, and as $xy-z^2$ is irreducible, we have $dim(L) = dim(H) -1$ by principal ideal theorem.

Im not sure how to show the last part.

The regular functions on $H$ are $k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ and the ideal of regular functions vanishing on $L$ is $(x,z)$ so I need to show $k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2) \cap (x,z)$ is not principal.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to consider the grading.

$$\require{cancel}(x,z)/(xy - z^2) = k\{x,z\} + k\{x^2,xy,xz,yz\} + k\{x^2,x^2y,x^2z,xyz,xy^2,y^2z\} +\cdots$$

So the dimensions are $2,4,6,\dots$.

On the other hand, what does the grading look like for $(f)/(xy-z^2)$? It would be

$$ k\{f\}+ \frac{k\{xf,yf,zf\}}{z^2 \sim xy} + \cdots $$

Ok, so we can't really get an explicit basis for the higher degree terms but we can see an issue with $k\{f\}$ as this is one dimensional.